# splitting fields $X^4-2,X^4+2X^2-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ field extension of $\mathbb Q$.

1) Show $L$ is the splitting field of the polynomail $p:=X^4-2$

Now the roots of the given polynomial are $\pm\sqrt[4]{2},\pm i\sqrt[4]{2}$, these are in $L$. On the other hand $i=1/2 * i\sqrt[4]{2}*(\sqrt[4]{2})^3$ so $\mathbb Q(\pm\sqrt[4]{2},\pm i\sqrt[4]{2})\subset L$. So $L$ is the splitting field of $p$.

2) What is the degree of $L$ over $\mathbb Q$ and what are the $\mathbb Q$-automorphisms of $L$.

I've got $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb Q] = 4$ and $[\mathbb Q(i):\mathbb Q] = 2$. So from this I can conclude $[L:\mathbb Q]\leq8$ **right** (as I can form 8 products of the different basis, after which all further are linear dependant)? Now how can I reason immedietly that $[L:\mathbb Q]\geq8$? Does this argument work: $(x^2+1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ (else it would have a root allready) so $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i):\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})]=2$. Now there are $8$ such automorphisms (permutating the roots).

3) Show that $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2}+i)$.

Here if I extend the identity $\mathbb Q\rightarrow\mathbb Q$ to $\sigma: L\rightarrow L$, $\sigma (\sqrt[4]{2}+i)=\sigma(\sqrt[4]{2})+\sigma(i)$, for this like shown above there are $8$ possibilitys $=[L:\mathbb Q]$ so $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2}+i)$.

4) Calculate the splitting field $L$ of $X^4+2X^2-2$ over $\mathbb Q$ and $[L:\mathbb Q]$.

Here the roots are $\pm \sqrt{-1+\sqrt3},\pm i\sqrt{1+\sqrt3}$, which are irrational as the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ because of Eisenstein. So I've got $[U:=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1+\sqrt3}):\mathbb Q]=4$ and of the second root the minimal polynomial in $U$ is $X^2+\sqrt 3 +1$ so the degree is $8$. Now here im not sure how I can justify the irreducibility of this polynomial (I maybe could go to $\mathbb Z(\sqrt{-1+\sqrt3})$ and show it there, but there I would need to show that $\sqrt 3 +1$ is prime but I would also need to show that this ring if an UFD). **Or is there another argument I could use?**

5) Calculate the splitting field $L$ over $\mathbb Q$ of ${P:=X^4+1,Q:=X^5+2}$ and it's degree.

Here $Q$ is irreducible after Eisenstein, $P(X+1)=X^4+4X^3+6X^2+4X+2$ Eisenstein ($f\mapsto f(X+1)$ is automorphism of $\mathbb Q[X]$), so they are minimal polynomials, and their degrees are coprime, $4,5$ so $[L:\mathbb Q]=20$ and $L=\mathbb Q(e^{i\pi/4},2^{1/5}e^{i\pi/5})$

**Question:** Please let me know if I did some mistakes!

Comment: I just noticed I can again argue that the roots aren't real, so it has to be irreducible. But is there a more general argument? I mean in a different case I might have to show that two (real) roots (with their "basis") aren't linear dependent, or in other words aren't algebraic dependent. Or can I show it without using that I can look at the rationals as subfield of the complex numbers. Maybe only with "Kronecker's extension".

Comment: You seem to be assuming ${\bf Q}(e^{2\pi i/5}\root5\of2)={\bf Q}(e^{2\pi i/5},\root5\of2)$, which is not the case.

Comment: For 4), a polynomial of degree 2 is irreducible unless it has a root in the field, and the roots of this polynomial are non-real, while the field is contained in the reals.

Comment: Any thoughts about my comments?

Comment: Here is a question about (4).
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465840/galois-group-of-x4-2x2-2

Comment: In part 1) of your solution, can you say that the splitting field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{4}},i)$?